# Iterating through an XML gives me only first element on PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to print the output of the  inside  that are inside multiple  but i could only print the first  value only using foreach expression. Tried a lot of hours but cannot make it work.

Here is a part of the XML output and the foreach function to iterate with.

```
<ad>
    <other_data>
        <other>
            <![CDATA[Parrilla]]>
        </other>
    </other_data>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Dormitorio con placard]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Dormitorio en suite]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Baño]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Baño en suite]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Living]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Cocina comedor]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Entrepiso]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Lavadero cubierto]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Galería semicubierta]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
    <ambients>
        <ambient>
            <type>
                <![CDATA[Galpón]]>
            </type>
            <length>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </length>
            <width>
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </width>
            <floor>
                <![CDATA[Cerámicos]]>
            </floor>
        </ambient>
    </ambients>
</ad>
XML;
```

//XML loads great but then i cant get each item of ambients->ambient.

```
$person = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$Ambients = $person->ambients->ambient;

foreach($Ambients as $Ambient){
          echo $Ambient->type;
}
```

Comment: Since there is one *type* per each *ambient*, iterate both at same level. Adjust `$Ambients = $person->ambients;` and `echo $Ambient->ambient->type;` https://rextester.com/TRHZP53334

Comment: That did the trick, tried several combinations but this is the only one that worked!!! Thanks you really helped me!!!!